# How to replace semicolon with newline?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to replace semicolon with new line.
i.e. whenever semicolon applears it has to move to new line.
I tried `.replace()`. It was not working for new line but was working for some other string. One more problem is only the first semicolon will be replaced.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<p>{{X.content.replace(';', '\n')}} </pre>
```

This was not working, then i tried with:

```
<p> {{X.content.replace(';', 'REPLACE')}} </p>
```

The code was working with any other string but only the first semicolon (;) will be replaced.

I want this to be converted and appear in the new line

> first line; second line; third line;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different things going wrong for you:

#### Only thie first semicolon is replaced:

This is the default for JavScript.  A regex will replace the rest.

```
X.content.replace(/;/g, '\n')
```

#### The newlines don't show up:

This is because HTML does not respect newlines by default.  You seam to have realised this because you have writen `<p></pre>` (which is odd and broken).

Either:
Replace `;` with `\n` and then use a well formed pre:

```
<pre>{{X.content.replace(/;/g, '\n')}}</pre>
```

Or:
Replace `;` with `<br />` and then declare the result as html:
(Warning: this option leaves you open to injection attacks so you need to make sure you trust the content)

```
<p ng-bind-html="X.content.replace(/;/g, '<br />')"></p>
```

---

*EDIT:*

Probably a better approach for you would be to forget all that and just do:

```
<p ng-repeat="line in X.content.split(';')">{{line}}</p>
```

This is less risky and results in nicer HTML to style as you choose.

Comment: Thanks a lot. <p ng-repeat="line in X.content.split(';')">{{line}}</p> This worked fine for me

Answer (score 3):

You need a regex with global flag to change all instances

```
X.content.replace(/;/g, '\n')
```

this is not something you should be doing in the view. Suggest you create a filter or modify the data in controller

Answer (score 0):

try like this here is one working example

```
var x ="dsdfs;sfsf;fdsfs"
console.log(x)//"dsdfs;sfsf;fdsfs"

var y  =x.replace(/;/g, " \n ")
 console.log(y)
 //"dsdfs 
   sfsf 
   fdsfs"
```